# Unbale to get filepath with filename outside function in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Okay so i am doing a java project for my college on out academic time table system. So i have made the entire UI with my member partners. However on trying to integrate it with other classes, i am facing errors and i need to call some values which i can pass to other classes. in my case i need to import 5 csv files and pass it on to another class. however due to some strange reasons, this is not happening. i have tried to make everything public just so that i can get the value, but even then nothing is happening. i am for the sake of convinience just interested in displaying it outside the function inside any function. if someone can help me there am sure i can call them to other classes on my own. below is the code for the importing class. kindly help me out :-

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author SUSMITA SAHA
 */
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class Screen1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private final JFileChooser openfile;
    public String filename = "";
    public String filename1 = "";
    public String filename2 = "";
    public String filename3 = "";
    public String filename4 = "";

    /**
     * Creates new form Screen
     */
    public Screen1() {
        initComponents();
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        openfile = new JFileChooser();
        openfile.setCurrentDirectory(new File("G:\\Java Project\\AcademicTimeTableSystem"));
        openfile.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV files", "csv"));

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("INPUT SCREEN");

        jLabel2.setText("COURSES");

        jLabel3.setText("INSTRUCTORS");

        jLabel4.setText("ROOMS");

        jLabel5.setText("SECTIONS");

        jLabel6.setText("TIMESLOTS");

        jLabel7.setText("Enter the csv file");

        jLabel8.setText("Enter the csv file");

        jLabel9.setText("Enter the csv file");

        jLabel10.setText("Enter the csv file");

        jLabel11.setText("Enter the csv file");

        jButton1.setText("BROWSE");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("BROWSE");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("BROWSE");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("BROWSE");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setText("BROWSE");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jButton6.setText("IMPORT");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6))
                .addGap(127, 127, 127)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel7)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 853, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton1))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel8)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton2))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel9)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton3))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel10)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton4))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel11)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton5)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(322, 322, 322)
                        .addComponent(jButton6)))
                .addGap(44, 44, 44))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(539, 539, 539)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9)
                    .addComponent(jButton3))
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jLabel10)
                    .addComponent(jButton4))
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addComponent(jLabel11)
                    .addComponent(jButton5))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 78, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton6)
                .addGap(24, 24, 24))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    public void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed
         int returnVal = openfile.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
          // jLabel9.setText(openfile.getSelectedFile().toString());
            jLabel8.setText(openfile.getSelectedFile().toString());
            filename1 = openfile.getSelectedFile().toString();
            System.out.println(filename1);  //here the output is displayed
        }
        else
        {
            jLabel8.setText("Please Choose the file");
        }
        System.out.println(filename1);  //here the output is displayed
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton5ActionPerformed
           int returnVal = openfile.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
          // jLabel9.setText(openfile.getSelectedFile().toString());
            jLabel11.setText(openfile.getSelectedFile().toString());
            filename4 = openfile.getSelectedFile().toString();
        }
        else
        {
            jLabel11.setText("Please Choose the file");
        }
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton5ActionPerformed

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
        int returnVal = openfile.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
          // jLabel9.setText(openfile.getSelectedFile().toString());
            jLabel7.setText(openfile.getSelectedFile().toString());
            filename = openfile.getSelectedFile().toString();
        }
        else
        {
            jLabel7.setText("Please Choose the file");
        }
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton3ActionPerformed
          int returnVal = openfile.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
          // jLabel9.setText(openfile.getSelectedFile().toString());
            jLabel9.setText(openfile.getSelectedFile().toString());
            filename2 = openfile.getSelectedFile().toString();
        }
        else
        {
            jLabel9.setText("Please Choose the file");
        }
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton3ActionPerformed

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton4ActionPerformed
        int returnVal = openfile.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
          // jLabel9.setText(openfile.getSelectedFile().toString());
            jLabel10.setText(openfile.getSelectedFile().toString());
            filename3 = openfile.getSelectedFile().toString();
        }
        else
        {
            jLabel10.setText("Please Choose the file");
        }
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton4ActionPerformed

    int a = 0;

    protected void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

        System.out.println(filename1);  //here the output is NOT displayed AT ANY CIRCUMSTANCES
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Screen1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Screen1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Screen1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Screen1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Screen1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

I am also giving a drive link incase that is easier

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EQqJTbptZv-cxXev1idwhD1hT369_XTR?usp=sharing

Comment: jButton6 has no `ActionListener` attached. I suppose you will use it for this import.

Comment: yes, for now it's just printing the output.

Comment: In the code that is given, the button does nothing. There is simply no related action with it. If this is not the problem, say exactly what you want to do when you hit it. It is clear that you want to pass the roads to another object, but who is it? Do the frame and this mysterious object know each other?

Comment: the import button is used to send the file paths with file names to some other classes. currently on clicking the button, i am just printing the filename with file path

Answer (score 0):

As I said, **jButton6** does not do anything right now because there is no `ActionListener` attached. To fix this problem, the **jButton6ActionPerformed** function must be associated with the button:

```
...
jButton6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
jButton6.setText("IMPORT");
jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
...
```

The standard way to transmit data between objects is by injection, either with a constructor or with a setter. This class illustrates both variants. Keep in mind that it is nice to use collections to work with unified data such as file paths.

```
public class SecondClass {
    private List<String> list;

    public SecondClass() {
    }

    public SecondClass(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

You can use the following code to submit data in this class:

```
protected void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    java.util.List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(filename);
    list.add(filename1);
    list.add(filename2);
    list.add(filename3);
    list.add(filename4);

    // inject with constructor
    SecondClass secondClassA = new SecondClass(list);

    // inject with setter
    SecondClass secondClassB = new SecondClass();
    secondClassB.setList(list);
}
```

If you want to use an already constructed object on which to submit the files, you can use something like this:

```
public class SecondClass  implements Consumer<List<String>> {
    private List<String> list;

    @Override
    public void accept(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}

public class Screen1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Consumer<java.util.List<String>> consumer;

    public void setConsumer(Consumer<java.util.List<String>> consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    protected void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
        java.util.List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(filename);
        list.add(filename1);
        list.add(filename2);
        list.add(filename3);
        list.add(filename4);

        if(consumer != null) {
            consumer.accept(list);
        }
    }

    ....

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                SecondClass secondClass = new SecondClass();

                Screen1 screen1 = new Screen1();
                screen1.setConsumer(secondClass);
                screen1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If the objects do not know each other, a mediator is known to know both of them:

```
public class Mediator implements Consumer<List<String>> {
    private static Mediator INSTANCE;

    private final List<Consumer<List<String>>> consumers = new ArrayList<>();

    private Mediator() {
    }

    public static Mediator getInstance() {
        if(INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new Mediator();
        }

        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void register(Consumer<List<String>> consumer) {
        consumers.add(consumer);
    }

    public void unregister(Consumer<List<String>> consumer) {
        consumers.remove(consumer);
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(List<String> list) {
        consumers.stream().forEach(c -> c.accept(list));
    }
}
```

Accordingly, all objects that want to receive messages from the mediator are registered.

```
public class SecondClass  implements Consumer<List<String>> {
    private List<String> list;

    public SecondClass() {
        Mediator.getInstance().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

And those who send messages send them to the mediator:

```
public class Screen1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    protected void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
        java.util.List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(filename);
        list.add(filename1);
        list.add(filename2);
        list.add(filename3);
        list.add(filename4);

        Mediator.getInstance().accept(list);
    }

    ....

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                SecondClass secondClass = new SecondClass();

                Screen1 screen1 = new Screen1();
                screen1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```